# Android - IllegalStateException : cursor.getString(idx) must not be null

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have follow all the stuffs here, but Why does `cursor.getString(idx)` said it must not be `null`? I supply all the necessary params..

here's my `getfilepath`:

```
fun getFilePathFromUri(context: Context, imageURI: Uri): String? {

        var cursor : Cursor? = null
        var result: String

        try {
            val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(imageURI, projection, null, null, null)

            if (cursor == null) {
                result = imageURI.path
            } else {
                Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "Path_img = " + imageURI)
                Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "Path_pth = " + imageURI.path)
                Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "Path_cursor = " + cursor)

                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val idx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
                result = cursor.getString(idx)
            }
            return result
        } finally {
                cursor!!.close()
        }
    }
```

here's the error:

```
12-04 14:34:44.971 2008-2008/com.xxx.project k E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx.proj, PID: 2008
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: cursor.getString(idx) must not be null
    at com.xxx.proj.utils.ImageUtils$Companion.getFilePathFromUri(ImageUtils.kt:78)
    at com.xxx.proj.api.Layer.createNewLayer(Layer.java:84)
    at com.xxx.proj.dialog.EventMapCreationDialog.registerNewMap(EventMapCreationDialog.kt:266)
    at com.xxx.proj.dialog.EventMapCreationDialog.onClick(EventMapCreationDialog.kt:82)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) of cursor.getString():

> Returns the value of the requested column as a String.
>
> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column
>   value is null or the column type is not a string type is
>   implementation-defined.

You're getting an `IllegalStateException`. Though broad, this generally means that a method has been invoked at a wrong/illegal time. That is, the the application or environment is not in the proper state for this method. This could mean that the parameter, cursor, or value is null.

Check the return type of the column before calling the method:

```
if (cursor.getType(idx) == FIELD_TYPE_STRING) {
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Comment: 'cursor.getString(idx)' return a string like this 'android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@c4fe18c'
where 'idx = 0'

Comment: So it's returning the memory address of the object. What line of your code is giving you trouble?

Comment: "result = cursor.getString(idx)"  <--- this line

Comment: what should the 'result' have??

Comment: `result` should be the column value as a string.

Comment: Try logging/printing the value of result to see if it's what you would expect at that column index.

Comment: string like the path --->  '/document/image:44373'
or the name of image itself??

Comment: see my first comment. returns a memory address?

Comment: Yes, it's logging a memory address. But, presumably, there is a value stored at that address. Try calling `result.toString()` to see what is stored there.

Comment: well, that did not happen, logging the result gives me nothing(as in print nothing), and that's my case.

Comment: Try posting the full stack trace for the error and it might show more of what is going on.

Comment: Try checking if `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns true or false. If it's false, then the cursor is empty, not necessarily null. If it's false, the column might exist, as it would in the method call `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)`, but it may have a null value.

Comment: "cursor.moveToFirst()" returns true

Comment: bro, I log the cursor.getString(idx), and it prints null

Comment: Then that means there is no value stored at that column. so you're retrieving a null value, which will throw an exception. Can you check your database that there will be a value there?

Comment: I check that the column type I'm getting is FIELD_TYPE_NULL which always returns a null... BTW in other device(galaxy s4 - < 6.0) it's working, but mine(nexus 7 - 6.0) it's not...
 Your thoughts?  [column types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType(int))

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't work on your device..but what you could do to get around it is call `cursor.getType(idx)` to see if it returns `FIELD_TYPE_NULL`. If it does, don't make the call to `cursor.getString(idx)`, which will avoid the exception.

Comment: yes, it will avoid the exception but it won't have any result either. huhu

Comment: Well, if the column is stored as `FIELD_TYPE_NULL`, your result to return will be null regardless...is it an issue to first initialize it to null?

Comment: bro, it is in the directory of image that gives me a bad day.
I try to select the image from PHOTOS and not to default gallery and gives me a birthday gift haha. It's the update by Google? and I'll try to investigate. Thanks for your time bro..