# Android exception: cursor.getString(cursor.…ColumnIndex("bucket_id")) must not be null

Tags: android, android-cursor

How can I call `cursor.getString()` for 'bucket_id' and 'bucket_display_name' above Android Q? Can I just use `MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID` replace 'bucket_id' to avoid this crash?

Of course, I know I can avoid get the String like below, which is answered at [cursor-getstringidx-must-not-be-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626959/android-illegalstateexception-cursor-getstringidx-must-not-be-null)

```
if (cursor.getType(idx) == FIELD_TYPE_STRING) {
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the situation that occurred was that, in Android Q any media files (images, videos etc) in the root directory, the folder name will be returned as null (in case of Internal Storage). In previous versions, it's been returned as 0 as album name. Just check for null for returned folder name and assign some default album name and you can avoid this crash I guess.